# Can I create view in my database server from another database server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view, connection

Is it possible to create view in my database server of another servers database table?

Let's say you have a database called `Testing` on `server1` and you have another database `Testing2` on `server2`. Is it possible to create view of `Testing2`'s table `Table2` in `server1`'s database `Testing`?

Also, I am using SQL Server 2008.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks,

Comment: Depends on the **database product** you're using (SQL is only the query language - **not** a product....)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can.  First, you need to link to the other server, using something like `sp_addlinkedserver`.

Then you can access the data using 4-part naming.  Here is an example:

```
create view v_server1_master_tables as
    select *
    from server1.master.information_schema.tables;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is possible through linked servers. However, I wouldn't encourage you to create views based on tables from another server, as it's likely that entire table will be selected from linked server every time you use this view - optimizer may not know about this table structure to issue any filters.
I've seen it at work, where nobody knew where `select * from` queries on large table come from that were slowing down the database, and it appeared that it was being used somwhere in another server, in a simple query.
At least you should check if your solution won't cause the above problem. Maybe someone else could elaborate on how optimizer behave when dealing with linked servers?