# Can I create a view that will query a table from another sql server on another server but same domain

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2000

I need to query a table from another SQL Server on a different server but same domain, but I am not sure how I will be able to do it.

I tried solution given in this answer [Can I create view in my database server from another database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573796/can-i-create-view-in-my-database-server-from-another-database-server) but it doesn't work for me as I got SQL Server 2000 (please don't hate :-) ).

When I try solution given then i get this error,

```
Line 23: Incorrect syntax near '-'.
```

which is because command is not compatible with SQL Server 2000.

**Edit**

```
SELECT * FROM AnotherServer.AnotherServerDatabase.Server.Table1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can link the servers and run cross server queries as long as you put the server name before the DB your running the query on.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM "linkedserver".dbo.aTable
```

(without "" marks )

bear in mind different server versions though. I run cross server queries from 2008 to 2000 servers and its a pain adapting :)